# Mercurial: Two Windows developers, central repository on my PC. Should I work in the central repository or clone from it?

Tags: mercurial

Is it okay to work in the central repository itself, or is that a "no-no?"  Let's say on my PC I have the central repository called C:\Src.  Is it okay for me to develop right in that repository itself or is that bad form?

Would it be better to clone a new directory called C:\MySrc?

C:\Src is shared on the network and the other developer of course cloned from that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would work on a clone of the repository, especially if you are working with multiple developers. In my typical workflow I will make frequent check-ins when I reach a certain point and want to pull down new changes from other developers then once I get to a good state for sharing I push to the central repository.

You may want to also check out using *hg serve* for sharing instead of using a fileshare as it may work more reliably for you.

Comment: One way to avoid accidentally working in the "central-ish" repository is to `hg update null` which removes the working directory entirely (technically it updates to the revision before the first revision, a point when no files existed)

Answer (score 1):

When first working with repositories, you want to focus on the concepts of version control and not get overwhelmed with the "where's my code" anxiety that comes from having more locations than necessary.  For this reason, with two developers just getting started I would recommend you each have a single repo which you sync *only* via pulls from each other.  You both need to either unc share or web serve your repos to do that.

I say to only use pulls so that you are always in control of which code has been brought into your repo.  This also makes sure that the extension I recommend next is always invoked.

I would also recommend using [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/), since you are on Windows, as well as the `fetch` extension (which you can configure to be used automatically during pulls in the Repository Explorer).  This will greatly reduce the number of manual steps to keep you in sync when pulling.  I do not recommend the `rebase` extension as I've lost valuable work when using it.

Mozilla's [Mercurial guidelines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/mercurial) are a good place to start with `mercurial.ini` as well.

Comment: I still find that TortoiseHG works ok for some people, but my own experience is that it complicates things and usually results in merge mishaps because someone did the wrong thing or never did push/pull. Instead I usually just write out a simple workflow on their whiteboard. clone == setup; fetch == get new updates; ci == check in my changes; push == tell everyone about my changes

Comment: It's perfectly analogous to the command line in my experience and I can't say I see any complication due to it, but I can say that there is certainly the convenience of calling functions from Explorer's context menu which saves time over navigating manually if you don't live in the command line.  The gui also puts more info at your fingertips without having to memorize commands.

Answer (score 1):

Using a local clone enables you to use commands such as hg incomming to see what changes your colleague has pushed. I also recommend using clones as this will result in both of you using the same workflow to apply/retreive changes.

Answer (score 0):

In mercurial there is no central repository. So you can use the repository in your pc directly, there is no need to clone.

Comment: While technically there is no central repository, it is common convention to have one place that is considered "central" that other users pull/push from. As a result of this team convention I would recommend still treating it as "central" as it is the teams "official" copy of the source code.

Comment: @Aaron-Weiker I see your point. I would say that in a setup like this it is better to clone!

Comment: I agree with Aaron, we use the same set up for just the Idea of this is where we make the build from and this code is always `good`

Answer (score 0):

Another method for working in the central repo but retaining some control is to allow users to create named branches for their work in the central repo. For example, I may create named branches named "dls_case1", "dls_case2", etc... Then, I am free to push to these named branches without exposing my changes to the wider group. A project lead, or whoever really, can them merge these branches in when appropriate.

Of course, unless you have a good reason I would side with Aaron Weiker and just make developer clones. I just wanted to point out another valid method.